# Deadlock when calling an async method inside a non async action

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

We have a web application which consists of a Web API consumed by our UI. The web application is installed on different servers (tests before installing it by our clients).

On one server, we get a deadlock by the following endpoint:

```
[HttpGet, Route(Order = 1)]
public IHttpActionResult GetUserDetails(long userKey)
{
    var userService = ResolveService<IUserService>();
    var nameService =  ResolveService<INameService >();

    LoggInfo("Start userService.Get()"); //logged in logs
    var result = userService.Get(userKey);
    this.LoggInfo($"End userService.Get() with id = "{result.Id}); // logged in logs

    try
    {
      LoggInfo($"Start nameService.Get()"); // logged in logs
      result.Name =  nameService.Get(result.Namekey).Result?.Name;
      LoggInfo($"End nameService.Get()"); // not logged in logs
    }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
     LogError("An error occured in NameService"); // not logged in logs
   }

    return Ok(result);
}
```

`nameService.Get(id)` is an `async` method :

```
public async Task<NameDTO> GetAsync(long key)
{
    LogInfo("start NameService.Get()"); // not logged in logs
    var query = GetQuery();
    var name = await query.Select(MapName())
                          .FirstOrDefaultAsync(n => n.Key == key);

    return name;
}
```

When I remove the async signature everything is working as expected, according to [this article](https://medium.com/rubrikkgroup/understanding-async-avoiding-deadlocks-e41f8f2c6f5d) it is normal to have a deadlock.

Could you please explain me why this works in the other servers ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Why don't you just make `GetUserDetails` async, then use the proper await syntax on your asynchronous calls?

Comment: Did this `query.Select(MapName()).FirstOrDefaultAsync(n => n.Key == key)` not completed synchronously on server with deadlock, and completed synchronously on other servers?

Comment: @Mason, I know the the approach above is not good, I just want understand why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @PetSerAi, Yes this is the issue, please note that the query  it doesn't take many time (When I run the generated query in sql developer)

Answer (score 2):

> Could you please explain me why this works in the other servers?

In order for [the deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) to occur, there are three necessary parts:

1. A one-thread-at-a-time context, which all servers would have (the pre-Core ASP.NET context).
2. An `await` (without `ConfigureAwait(false)`) that [acts asynchronously](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).
3. Code elsewhere that blocks a thread inside that context, waiting for the `async` method to finish. All servers also have this.

Most likely, the difference in behavior is due to the second part: an `await` that acts asynchronously. [`await` first examines its awaitable (e.g., the `Task` passed to it), and if that awaitable is complete, then it continues executing the `async` method *synchronously*](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Specifically, this would happen if the `Task<NameDTO>` returned from `GetAsync` completed *before* the calling code hit the `.Result`. This would have to be extremely fast, but it's possible depending on caching, how fast your network hop is, how much the code is slowed down by load/neighbors/anti-virus, etc.

Comment: I have added some logs and I figured ou that havs never called, any idea ?

Comment: @BilelChaouadi: Well, if it's never called, then it would never deadlock...

Comment: What could be then, I have wrapped the call to the nameService.Get() inside a try catch and I have added some logs in the in the catch block but no error has been logged!!

Comment: @BilelChaouadi: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I have updated my question, the issue is that my endPoint is not responding, no logs in nameService and no error occured, it seems that the nameService.Get never hitted